# Custom property attributes in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, attributes, properties

Can custom property attributes be created in Objective-C just like in VB.NET? For example, in VB.NET you can create the "Browsable" attribute and read it at runtime to determine whether you should display a property or not.

```
Public Class Employee
    <Browsable(True)> _
    Public Property Property1() As String
        Get

        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)

        End Set
    End Property

    <Browsable(False)> _
    Public Property Property2() As String
        Get

        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)

        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I would like to do the same in Objective-C, even if it is a fixed attribute that can only be set at compile time and cannot be changed at all.

What I'm trying to do is to add an attribute to properties of my class to determine whether the properties should be serialized or not.

I know the standard Objective-C attributes (readonly, nonatomic, etc.), but those don't help me... unless you have a creative way of using them. I also looked into using C attributes with the `__attribute__(("Insert attribute here"))` keyword, but C has specific attributes that serve specific purposes, and I'm not even sure you can read them at runtime. If I missed one that can help me, let me know.

I tried using `typdef`. For example:

```
typdef int serializableInt;
serializableInt myInt;
```

and use the `property_getAttributes()` Objective-C runtime function, but all it tells me is that myInt is an int. I guess typedef is pretty much like a macro in this case... unless I can create a variable of type serializableInt at runtime. Anyhow, here's [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101) on the values you get from `property_getAttributes()`.

The other requirement is that this attribute has to work with NSObject sub-classes as well as primitive data types. I thought about the idea of adding to the class a black lists or white lists as an ivar that would tell me which properties to skip or serialize, which is basically the same idea. I'm just trying to move that black/white list to attributes so it's easy to understand when you see the header file of a class, it's consistent across any class I create and it's less error prone.

Also, this is something to consider. I don't really need the attribue to have a value (TRUE or FALSE; 1, 2, 3; or whatever) because the attribute itself is the value. If the attribute exists, then serialize; otherwise, skip.

Any help is appreciated. If you know for sure that this is not possible on Objective-C, then let me know. Thanks.

Comment: How about creating a class method that returns an array with the names of the serialisable instance variables?

Comment: I thought of that and it is a perfect solution. But my question is specifically about solving this problem with attributes. Do custom attributes even exist in Objective-C?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add attribute to property, class, method or ivar, you can try to use [github.com/libObjCAttr](https://github.com/epam/lib-obj-c-attr). It's really easy to use, add it via cocoapods, and then you can add attribute like that:

```
@interface Foo

RF_ATTRIBUTE(YourAttributeClass, property1 = value1)
@property id bar;

@end
```

And in the code:

```
YourAttributeClass *attribute = [NSDate RF_attributeForProperty:@"bar" withAttributeType:[YourAttributeClass class]];
// Do whatever you want with attribute, nil if no attribute with specified class
NSLog(@"%@", attribute.property1)
```

Answer (score 1):

unless i've missed your point…

i'd recommend declaring a protocol. then using instances of objc objects as variables in your objc classes which adopt the protocol.

```
@interface MONProtocol

- (BOOL)isSerializable;
- (BOOL)isBrowsable;

/* ... */

@end

@interface MONInteger : NSObject <MONProtocol>
{
    int value;
}

- (id)initWithInt:(int)anInt;

@end

@interface MONIntegerWithDynamicProperties : NSObject <MONProtocol>
{
    int value;
    BOOL isSerializable;
    BOOL isBrowsable;
}

- (id)initWithInt:(int)anInt isSerializable:(BOOL)isSerializable isBrowsable:(BOOL)isBrowsable;

@end

// finally, a usage
@interface MONObjectWithProperties : NSObject
{
    MONInteger * ivarOne;
    MONIntegerWithDynamicProperties * ivarTwo;
}

@end
```

if you want to share some implementation, then just subclass NSObject and extend the base class.

you'd then have a few variants to write for the types/structures you want to represent.

Comment: I think you have missed his point.  He doesn't want to say the object is browsable or serializable, but that a property within the object is serializable or browsable.

Comment: @ncipollina there is no property attribute, so i recommended composition.

Answer (score 1):

The deficiency with the other answers I've seen so far is that they are implemented as instance methods, i.e., you need to have an instance already before you can query this metadata. There are probably edge cases where that's appropriate, but metadata about classes should be implemented as class methods, just as Apple does, e.g.:

```
+ (BOOL)automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:(NSString*)key { }
```

We could imagine our own along similar lines:

```
+ (BOOL)keyIsBrowsable:(NSString*)key { }
```

or

```
+ (NSArray*)serializableProperties { }
```

Let's imagine our class is called `FOOBar`, and we want to know whether the `baz` key is browsable. Without having to create a `FOOBar` we can just say:

```
if ([FOOBar keyIsBrowsable:@"baz"]} { ... }
```

You can do pretty much anything with this technique that can be done with custom attributes. (Except for things like the `Serializable` attribute which require cooperation from the compiler, IIRC.) The nice thing about custom attributes, though, is that it is easy to distinguish at a glance what is metadata and what is intrinsic to that class's actual functionality, but I think that's a minor gain.

(Of course, you may have to check for the existence of the `keyIsBrowsable:` selector, just as you'd have to check for the existence of a specific custom attribute. Again, custom attributes have a slight leg up here, since we can tell the .NET runtime to give them all to us.)

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a similar issue whe serializing objects. My solution is to add a `@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *serialProperties;` which has a custom getter that returns the names (as NSString*) of the properties of this (sub-)class that should be serialized.

For example:

```
- (NSArray *)serialProperties {
    return @[@"id", @"lastModified", @"version", @"uid"];
}
```

Or in a subclass:

```
- (NSArray *)serialProperties {
    NSMutableArray *sp = [super serialProperties].mutableCopy;
    [sp addObject:@"visibleName"];
    return sp;
}
```

You can then easily get all properties and their values via `[self dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:self.serialProperties]`.

Comment: @Bavarious already made this proposition in the comments—although he used a class method which is a more common approach to solve this. Roberto explicitly stated that the question is about custom "attributes" on properties.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed that comment. Maybe my snippets can still come in handy ;) However, AFAIK there is nothing like "attributes" in objective-c.

Comment: Well, properties do have attributes in the objc-runtime (like readonly, atomic, dynamic, weak, ...). Those attributes can be queried–yet they are not extendable.

Comment: Those "attributes" actually only describe how the getters/setters are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add custom properties other than what sdk has provided..
.
But there is a work around to attain your objective...

```
@interface classTest:NSObject

   @property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *firstName;

   @property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *lastName;

   @property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableDictionary *metaData;

@end
@implementation classTest

 - (id) init
{

 self = [super init];
 //Add meta data
  metaData=[[NSmutableDictionary alloc]init];

  //
  if( !self ) return nil;
  return self;
 }

@end
```

so use the dictionary to add and retrieve meta data...

i hope it helps....