# Can I specify custom attributes on members in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

When I declare a property, I can put various attributes in the declaration, which will have special meaning for the compiler:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *consumption;
```

Here, `nonatomic` and `retain` are attributes. Is it possible to add a custom attribute, and be able to check for the existance of this attribute at runtime ? For instance:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, test) NSNumber* consumption;
```

I am basically using for a construct that can replace the use of attributes as I know them from C#/.NET - so alternative suggestions are also welcomed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919021/custom-property-attributes-in-objective-c

Comment: @rishi, thanks, but I am not really satisfied with the answer to that question, since my specific situation does not allow me to create another return type. I am looking for an answer on whether or not it is possible - and if yes, then how.

Comment: It's not, unfortunately, without modifying the compiler.

Comment: @driis - i am not sure though whether it is possible or not, i will work on this to check if something like this is possible.

Comment: Here is a workaround https://github.com/railsware/BloodMagic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add attributes to `@property()` without modifying the compiler.

Note that, in general, grubbing even the existing attributes of `@property` declarations at runtime is quite thoroughly discouraged.   The runtime does offer an API via which you can do so, but it is not intended for general purpose use and will likely change in the future.

Comment: I just implemented a method that iterates through all the properties of a class and automatically create a RestKit mapping.  Why is grubbing through properties discouraged?

Comment: @Nick It is fragile.  Someone could arbitrarily add a property via category or in a superclass.  Or someone might create a setter/getter method pair without a property declaration. Or one might declare a property that isn't intended to participate in your RestKit mapping.   More issues for framework implementers than end applications, but you'll likely find that having an explicit "+(NSArray*)attributesParticipatingInRestMapping" type query method will reduce maintenance headaches over time.  Requiring the dev to add to that set manually isn't terribly onerous & it is self documenting.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add a NSDictionary of property names to an NSArray of attributes.  This can be stored in a base class or a seperate class that is associated with the original object via the  objc_setAssociatedObjects and objc_getAssociatedObjects API.

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) for information on these APIs.  It's not exactly what you're looking for since you will need to change the compiler, but is a way of adding metadata to any object.

Answer (score 0):

adding custom attributes to property is not common but desirable I think. this feature could be used for custom the traversal about properties of an class. i desired this feature when I handle SQL: if we have attributes like: `EXCLUDE_FROM_SELECT`, `INCLUDE_BY_INSERT`, `EXCLUDE_FROM_UPDATE`... then it would be very nice.

Actually, I am not sure if there is a way to enable it for the @property directive. however, we may beable to do something similar:

if you have a look at the objc/runtime.h you could found a function: `class_replaceProperty`, which not documented in the offical website. a similar function called `class_addProperty` is documented and could help you understand the argument of the previous one. Actually, I think the @property makes use of this functions to do the property settings (but I cannot proof it does).

you may also need the following functions:

```
void class_copyPropertyList(...);
void property_copyAttributeList(...);
void class_getProperty(...);
```

by using these functions, you could do something what @property actually does.

What i did for the previous SQL problem is to define 3 functions to register custom attributes:

```
void prepareClass(...);
void registerAttributes(...);
void endRegister(...);
```

And then we could do the register in the `+initialize`function of your tagart class.

However, making use of code (compare with simple @interface + @property declaration) may not be your best solution, because we may want to see the property settings directly from the declaration. And actually we could do it better by using `__attribute__((constructor))`and macros:

the @interface @end actually allow you doing this:

```
@interface MyVO : NSObject
__attribute__((constructor))
void prepareForMyVO(){ prepareClass(MyVO);}
@property (strong) id p1;
__attribute__((constructor))
static void registerAttrForP1(){ registerAttributes("p1", EXCLUDE_FROM_SELECT);}
@property (strong) id p2;
__attribute__((constructor))
static void registerAttrForP2(){ registerAttributes("p2", INCLUDE_BY_INSERT);}
@end
__attribute__((constructor))
static void endRegisterForMyOV(){ endRegister();};
```

therefore, you could define your macros to handle this hardcode:

```
#define $p(clazz, zuper) class : zuper \
__attribute__((constructor)) static void prepareFor ## clazz(){ prepareClass(#MyVO);}
#define $r(p, attr) p; \
__attribute__((constructor)) static void registerAttrFor ## p(){ registerAttributes(#p, attr);}
#define $e(clazz) __attribute__((constructor)) static void endRegister ## clazz(){ endRegister();};



@interface $p(MyVO, NSObject)
@property (strong) id $r(p1, EXCLUDE_FROM_SELECT);
@property (strong) id $r(p1, INCLUDE_BY_INSERT);

@end $e(MyVO)
```

PS:the above coding is not the exact coding, it just an example. And I am not sure if the last macro solution works
hope this could help.